# Angular2 accessing service object in index.html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a DataService which is supposed to get the textbox value, and pass it into my components. I was wondering is there a way to access the service object in my index.html file when the textbox value has changed? This is what I have tried so far:

DataService:

```
export interface Info{
  itemNo:string;
}

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

item:Info={itemNo:"Test"};

change(newItem:string){
  this.item.itemNo=newItem;
}
constructor(private http: Http) { }
}
```

I would like to access the change method from the service:

```
onSelect: function (request, response) {
    console.log(urlApi);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: urlApi,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                  this.item.change(response.items[0].item); //This is what I am trying to do
                 },
                error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
            });
        }
```

Could someone point out how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is with the "this" scope. If you are allowed to use ES6 you can use the new [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to get access to this.item. it might be as simple as.

```js
...
success: (response) =>{
  this.item.change(response.items[0].item); //This is what I am trying to do
}
...
```

Although with all that said you might be better off using Angular's [HTTP client](https://angular.io/guide/http) rather than jQuery